# The erase function of strings in c++

Tags: c++

well I was doing this problem from leetcode " https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-palindrome/ " and to remove the punctuations I used this

```
for (auto i:s)
{
    if (ispunct(i))
    {
        s.erase(remove(s.begin(), s.end(), i), s.end());
        continue;
    }    
}
```

but when it runs it leaves some punctuation characters in the string like this:
ip-> "Marge, let's "[went]." I await {news} telegram."
op-> "margelets[wentiawaitnewstelegram"

Comment: This code will not compile. Please post a real code.

Comment: If you have C++20, you may want to use [std::erase_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase2). If not, you can still consider the "equivalent to" blocks for the remove-erase idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying a string (or any other collection) while looping over it is a poor idea. Your iterator into the string is based on the state of the string at the beginning of your loop. Changing the state of the string *inside* the loop may lead to unexpected behavior of your iterator.

Rather you may want to create a new string without the offending characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
  std::string s1 = "Hello world!";
  std::string s2;

  std::copy_if(
    s1.begin(), s1.end(), 
    std::back_inserter(s2), 
    [](auto ch) { return !std::ispunct(ch); }
  );

  std::cout << s2 << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. can you tell me how can I pass the predicate to another function so I can implement more than one conditions

Comment: To use more than one condition, edit the lambda function `[](auto ch) { return !std::ispunct(ch); }` E.g. to remove punctuations character and the letter `'e'`:  `[](auto ch) { return !std::ispunct(ch) && ch != 'e'; }`